# Отладка JS в браузере

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование, frontend

Есть у меня `HTML` страница, к которой подключен `js`-код как внутренний, так и внешний.

Можно ли в Chrome сделать отладку кода, экспериментировать?

Внес правки, браузер их исполнил.

Есть окно `Reveal on sources panel`.
Правки делать можно, сохранять локально, но браузер их не выполняет.

Спасибо.

Comment: отлично прям, то что надо. никак не мог найти этой функции в Chrome и сейчас тоже.

Comment: я бы поддержал диалог - но серьезно :)

Answer (score 1):

Откройте dev tools, в нём вкладку Sources, ctrl+P - найдите нужный js-файл.

Произведите в нём изменения, нажмите ctrl+S. Ваши изменения кода будут учтены.

Продолжайте отладку, увидите, что работает изменённый код.

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую и отпишусь

Comment: Я только что ещё раз проверил - работает. Так что пишите, если не получится.